# zsh node not found. Have to switch to bash and then to zsh again

Tags: bash, npm, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using hyper terminal on Windows 10 with WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux). I've got wsl to default to zsh but whenever I run npm or node i get the "zsh: command not found: node" or npm. To fix this i have to enter "bash" let the terminal switch to bash and then enter "zsh" to switch back. After that node and npm commands work.

Please help! I tried looking at existing posts but didn't find anything relating to this issue.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Apparently your Zsh configuration files do not include the required `PATH` adjustment. Please reveal where `npm` is installed (in Bash, write the command `type -all npm`) and from that output, reveal which `.bashrc` or `.profile` or `.bash_profile` line contains the path (everything up to but excluding the final `/npm`).

Comment: Starting a new `zsh` from within Bash is slightly wrong. You can type `exec zsh` to replace Bash with a new `zsh` instance (and probably to begin with use `exec bash` to replace the original `zsh` instance with a `bash` instance).

Comment: Something is messing up with your PATH variable. Sourcing .zsh should be enough. But to fix you need to check your environment variables and who is changing it. Does this happen after some command?

Answer (score 8):

Just figured it out. Had to add the following in my .zshrc

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_comp$
```

Although this does make zsh take a long time to load initially.

Comment: It still not work for me.